# function to reduce redundancy for reading database in sqlite3

Tags: python, function, sqlite

Hi guys:) I'm a newbie at programming and would like to ask for help in creating a function to help reduce redundancy in my code. I have successfully created a database holding 5 different tables for data of different countries. All tables have the same structure (see attached screenshots for reference). My objective is to calculate the summation of all rows within all the different tables for a particular parameter (type of pollution).
I have managed to write code to only select the particular data I need of one country (I tried writing code to calculate the summation but I can't figure that out, so I decided to just select the data and then manually calculate the values myself with a calculator -I know that sort of defeats the purpose of programming but at my programming level (beginner) I feel like it's the only way that I can do the code) my issue is that I have five countries, so I don't want to repeat the same block of code for the different countries. this is my code for one country:

```
def read_MaltaData():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('FinalProjectDatabase.sqlite3')
    Malta = conn.cursor()
    Malta.execute("SELECT * FROM MaltaData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'")
    result = Malta.fetchall()
    print(result)
```

my result is this:

`[('Malta', 'Valletta', 'MT00005', 'Msida', 'PM10', 64.3, 'ug/m3', 'Traffic', 'urban', 14.489985999999998, 35.895835999489535, 2.0), ('Malta', None,` etc.

(I am going to manually calculate the data I require -in this case 64.3 + the value from the next row- as I don't know how to do it in python)

To clarify, my aim isn't to have a sum total across all the tables as one whole value (i.e. I don't want to add the values of all the countries all together). My desired output should look  something like this:

```
Malta    summation value
italy    summation value
france   summation value
```

and not like this

countries all together = one whole value (i.e. all summation values added together)

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Unfortunately I am not able to share the database with you, which is why I am sharing screenshots of it instead.

image of all 5 different tables in one database:
[image]

image of one table (all tables look the same, just with different values)
[image]

Comment: I know that this is not your question, but why are you using separate tables for countries? Especially if the structure is the same, it would be better to combine the five tables to one table. It also seems that there are already `Country` and `City` columns...

Comment: @Wolf i am doing a school assignment and the instructions in my assignment state to produce different tables for each country :)

Comment: Why do you name your function `read_MaltaData` if it actually *`print`s*? I guess this is because this function reads, but this is the inner perspective. My advice: familiarize to take the outer perspective when it comes to naming things.

Comment: hmm.. didnt know that what i name functions affects their performance. i just named it randomly. thanks for the insight!

Comment: Naming does not affect performance in the sense of execution speed but "development performance" in the long term, that is, the speed with which you can change things without breaking anything.

Comment: BTW: consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It doesn't take much time (just a minute or so) and is really informative, for instance you'll learn how to vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the country name as argument to the data retrieval function, you can generate the table names dynamically (note the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) arguments in `execute` and `print`):

### First draft

```py
def print_CountryData(country):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('FinalProjectDatabase.sqlite3')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT SUM(AirPollutionLevel) FROM {country}Data WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'")
    sumVal = cur.fetchone()[0]
    print(f"{country} {sumVal}")

# example call:
for country in ('France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Malta', 'Poland'):
    print_CountryData(country)
```

While building query strings your own with simple string functions is discouraged in the [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for security reasons, in your very case where you have total control of the actual arguments I'd consider it as safe.

This answer adapts the summation from the [great answer given by forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66208134/2932052) but refuses to move the repetition to SQL. It also shows both integration with python and output formatting.

### MRE-style version

This is an improved version of my first answer, transformed into a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and combined with output. Also, some performance improvements were made, for instance opening the database only once.

```py
import sqlite3
import random # to simulate actual pollution values

# Countries we have data for
countries = ('France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Malta', 'Poland')

# There is one table for each country
def tableName(country):
    return country+'Data'

# Generate minimal version of tables filled with random data
def setup_CountryData(cur):
    for country in countries:
        cur.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {tableName(country)}
                (AirPollutant text, AirPollutionLevel real)''')
        for i in range(5):
            cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO {tableName(country)} VALUES 
                    ('PM10', {100*random.random()})""")
                    
# Get sum up pollution data for each country
def print_CountryData(cur):
    for country in countries:
        cur.execute(f"""SELECT SUM(AirPollutionLevel) FROM 
                {tableName(country)} WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'""")
        sumVal = cur.fetchone()[0]
        print(f"{country:10} {sumVal:9.5f}")

# For testing, we use an in-memory database
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()
setup_CountryData(cur)

# The functionality actually required
print_CountryData(cur)
```

Sample output:

```
France     263.79430
Germany    245.20942
Italy      225.72068
Malta      167.72690
Poland     290.64190
```

It's often hard to evaluate a solution without actually trying it. That's the reason why questioners on StackOverflow are **constantly encouraged** to ask in this style: it makes it much more likely someone will understand and fix the problem ... *quickly*

Comment: I didn't like your haughty comment on my answer, even though you were right. so I just did what every wise 5 year old would have done, i downvoted yours. Anyway, as the conversation steered to a constructive discussion, take my upvote

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I myself have to learn more of pandas as it is great for structured querying of data *not* stored in SQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION ALL to get a row for each country:

```
SELECT 'France' country, SUM(AirPolutionLevel) [summation value] FROM FranceData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Germany' country, SUM(AirPolutionLevel) [summation value] FROM GermanyData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Italy' country, SUM(AirPolutionLevel) [summation value] FROM ItalyData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Malta' country, SUM(AirPolutionLevel) [summation value] FROM MaltaData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Poland' country, SUM(AirPolutionLevel) [summation value] FROM PolandData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'
```

Comment: Yes, `sqlite3` supports `union all`! Formatting the actual output can be done by `for rec in cursor.fetchall():
 print("{} {}".format(*rec))`

Answer (score 0):

If the database is not too big you could use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

This approach is less efficient than using SQL queries directly but can be used if you want to explore the data interactively in a notebook for example.

You can create a dataframe from your SQLite db using [`pandas.read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

and then perform your calculation using `pandas.DataFrame` methods, which are designed for this type of tasks.

For your specific case:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)

query = "SELECT * FROM MaltaData WHERE AirPollutant = 'PM10'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

# check dataframe content
print(df.head())
```

If I understood and then you want to compute the sum of the values in a given column:

```
s = df['AirPollutionLevel'].sum()
```

If you have missing values you might want to fill them with 0s before summing:

```
s = df['AirPollutionLevel'].fillna(0).sum()
```

Comment: Why using pandas if the database already does it for you? This solution is extremely inefficient. And you are obviously calculation the wrong sum. Did you try anything of that?

Comment: Because you can do it in 3 lines. And that's what I would have tried to start with. 
That said, as you don't know the size of the database I think that "extremely inefficient" could be an exaggeration. Sure, it would be more efficient to do it in SQL and especially with large databases, I agree that your solution is better in that case. Good job mate.
The purpose of my answer was to provide OP with an example of how SQLite databases can be read and manipulated quickly with pandas without having to write complex queries, helpful if you are someone who is not experienced in programming.

Comment: I see, and thanks for taking the time to reply. Please let me clarify my criticism: The most important problem here as is the case in OP's code and for most SQL beginners: They grab *all* data by `SELECT *` when they are only interested in one specific column. And since SQL also supports some aggregation function like `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` and so on we can reduce the data to be transferred even more, from one column to one cell. So the database engine can do the work in an efficient way upon the data that's already there. And as for the error: you should sum `AirPollutionLevel` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and for the constructive criticism. As an SQL beginner myself I learnt something useful from your answers

Comment: Thanks for fixing, I also tried your solution (with the test data of my MRE-style version) and the performance difference is really relevant. Maybe it's not really the data transfer but the pandas initialization what caused this.

Comment: Good to know! I thought it would have been comparable for a small db, but indeed there might be a big overhead for setting up the dataframe. So in the end you were right, it is indeed extremely inefficient. I need to educate myself more on SQL queries :)